# How not to send all traffic over SBS connection?

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-sbs

My girlfriend uses SBS Connection Manager to connect to her company's network. The problem is that the internet connection is überslow at work, so she wants to use the home internet connection to surf the web and use the SBS Connection to get to her work stuff.

Normally with a VPN connection you just have to uncheck a box "Send all traffic over VPN connection" or "Use VPN as default gateway" or something like that.

As I've never seen this SBS Connection Manager-thing before, I've no idea where to uncheck a similar box. (I've checked the properties of the connection in Network Connections, but it only has a few options about logging and firewall).

Thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards,
Niels R.

Answer (score 2):

Connection Manager is really just a way of pre-packaging a network connection with all the correct settings, so that it's a 'no brainer' for the end user to set up. The settings are pre-defined on the server side by the network administrator, so you can't edit the settings like you can with a normal VPN connection. Actually, on SBS, the Connection Manager profile is created automatically by the SBS VPN wizard, so not even the administrator gets to change the settings directly.

Connection Manager, however, is just a convenience. A user can choose to ignore Connection Manager and simply create a VPN connection manually. In fact, Connection Manager is not compatible with Windows Vista or Windows 7, so users of those systems cannot use it and have no choice but to create the connection manually.

The solution to your problem then, is to ignore the connection created by connection manager and manually create a new VPN connection to the server. The type must be PPTP but otherwise all the defaults should work. The address that you will be connecting to is generally the address of the 'Remote Web Workplace' or you may be able to determine it from the existing connection properties. You will then be able to edit the settings of the new connection to turn off the 'use default gateway' option.

This solution does not require any changes on the server. A standard user should be able to create this new VPN connection on their computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not really an option in this case.

Comment: I have used this solution many times myself and it does work. Why do you say it is not an option? I think perhaps you might have misunderstood the answer, so I have re-worded it to make it clearer what I meant.

Comment: +1 @Tim Long: the only other way would be to change the default route (google the `route` command) after the connection has been established to not use the VPN interface, but use your default gateway on your network; you can do a before and after connecting with the `route` command to see what it should look like.